# Creating a list in Python- something sneaky going on?

Tags: python, list, constructor

Apologies if this doesn't make any sense, I'm very new to Python!

From testing in an interpreter, I can see that `list()` and `[]` both produce an empty list:

```
>>> list()
[]
>>> []
[]
```

From what I've learned so far, the only way to create an object is to call its constructor (`__init__`), but I don't see this happening when I just type `[]`. So by executing `[]`, is Python then mapping that to a call to `list()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Python does not call `list()`, or you could affect what type `[]` creates by assigning to list, which you cant:

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>> __builtin__.list = set
>>> list()
set([])
>>> []
[]
```

`[]` is syntax for creating a list. It's a builtin type and it has special syntax, just like dicts and strings and ints and floats and lots of other types.

Creating instances of types can *also* be done by calling the type, like `list()` -- which will in turn call the type's constructor and initializer for you. Calling the initializer (`__init__`) directly does *not* create a new instance of the type. Calling the constructor (`__new__`) does, but you should not be calling it directly.

Answer (score 13):

Those two constructs are handled quite differently:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f(): return []
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> def f(): return list()
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              6 RETURN_VALUE        
>>>
```

The `[]` form constructs a list using the opcode `BUILD_LIST`, whereas the `list()` form calls the `list` object's constructor.

Answer (score 6):

**What are the key differences between using list() and []?**

The most obvious and visible key difference between list() and [] is the syntax. Putting the syntax aside for a minute here, someone whose new or intermediately exposed to python might argue that they’re both lists or derive from the same class; that is true. Which furthermore increases the importance of understanding the key differences of both, most of which are outlined below.

list() is a function and [] is *literal syntax*.

Let’s take a look at what happens when we call list() and [] respectively through the disassembler.

```
>>> import dis
>>> print(dis.dis(lambda: list()))
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
None
>>> print(dis.dis(lambda: []))
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

The output from the disassembler above shows that the literal syntax version doesn’t require a global lookup, denoted by the op code LOAD_GLOBAL or a function call, denoted by the op code CALL_FUNCTION.

As a result, literal syntax is faster than it’s counterpart. – Let’s take a second and look at the timings below.

```
import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('[]', number=10**4)
0.0014592369552701712
>>> timeit.timeit('list()', number=10**4)
0.0033833282068371773
```

On another note it’s equally important and worth pointing out that literal syntax, `[]` does not unpack values. An example of unpacking is shown below.

```
>>> list('abc') # unpacks value
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> ['abc'] # value remains packed
['abc']
```

**What’s a literal in python?**

Literals are notations or a way of writing constant or raw variable values which python recognises as built-in types.

Sourced from my post on [PythonRight - what's the difference between list and []](http://www.pythonright.com/whats-the-difference-between-list-and/).

Comment: I feel this answer deserves more credit than the rest of the answers that I have seen on this same topic (duplicates questions included)

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful @stormfield. 

Answer (score 5):

I started learning python yesterday....
I guess you would have to say its internally mapped

```
>>> a = []
>>> type(a)
<type 'list'>
>>> a = list()
>>> type(a)
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: +1 for diving in and answering questions on your second day of using Python!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other answers, from the [Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#list-displays):

> A list display is a possibly empty series of expressions enclosed in square brackets:
>
> ```
> list_display        ::=  "[" [expression_list | list_comprehension] "]"
> ...
> ```
>
> A list display yields a new list object.

It does not explicitly mention how "yielding a new list object" is implemented. It could well be a call to the `list()` constructor, like you mentioned. Or maybe lists, being so elementary, get special treatment, and `list()` is actually mapped to something different entirely.

Either way, `[]` is certainly not mapped to a call to the constructor of the type named `__builtins__.list`, because redefining that type still causes `[]` to return an actual list, as other answerers have shown.

Answer (score 3):

Python, like most programming langauges, has something called *literals*, meaning that special syntax can be used to write out some of the most important types of values. Very little of this is necessary, but it makes it easier to use Python that we can write literals.

```
>>> 0
0
>>> int()
0
>>> 5
5
>>> int('5') # I'm using a string literal here though!
5
>>> 0.0
0.0
>>> float()
0.0
>>> "" 
''
>>> str()
''
>>> u""
u''
>>> unicode()
u''
>>> ()
()
>>> tuple()
()
>>> {}
{}
>>> dict()
{}
```

When we make our own types (classes), we create instances of them using their constructors, like `list` for lists. When we use literals, it's sort of like syntactic sugar for calling `list`, but in reality it calls that same basic things behind the scene.

Answer (score 1):

Since :

```
class list(object):
    """
    list() -> new empty list
    list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
    """
```

If the element in your lists is an `iterable` (i.e. a `str`), the `list()` and `[]` don't work the same way.

So

```
>>> a = ['ab']
>>> b = list('ab')
>>> a[0]
'ab'
>>> b[0]
'a'
```