# mylist = list() vs mylist = [] in Python

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a list in Python- something sneaky going on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736693/creating-a-list-in-python-something-sneaky-going-on)
>   [Creating an empty list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972212/creating-an-empty-list-in-python)

Consider the following:

```
mylist = list()
```

and:

```
mylist = []
```

Is there any benefit to using `list()` or `[]` - should one be used over the other in certain situation?

Comment: I'm inclined to think the `[]` literal would be faster since it saves a function call, but I've been wrong before. Did you try measuring this?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi -- I'm pretty sure I've seen this in a SO post before.  I'll try to find it ...

Comment: I haven't tried measuring, I will try and update soon, thanks Frederic

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Isn't it just syntactic sugar? In that case it probably wouldn't save a function call.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi If it saves a function call, that would only be because no new object is allocated. In fact, new objects are allocated, so there is no difference.

Comment: Oh, but as @Sven notes, it saves a local lookup of `list`.

Comment: @DavidRobinson This is unlikely to be significant, but it is true.

Comment: This question is phrased better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For an empty list, I'd recommend using `[]`.  This will be faster, since it avoids the name look-up for the built-in name `list`.  The built-in name could also be overwritten by a global or local name; this would only affect `list()`, not `[]`.

The `list()` built-in is useful to convert some other iterable to a list, though:

```
a = (1, 2, 3)
b = list(a)
```

For completeness, the timings for the two options for empty lists on my machine (Python 2.7.3rc2, Intel Core 2 Duo):

```
In [1]: %timeit []
10000000 loops, best of 3: 35 ns per loop

In [2]: %timeit list()
10000000 loops, best of 3: 145 ns per loop
```

Comment: What about explicit > implicit? When I see "list()" I don't bat an eye. If I see "[]" I think twice, especially when I found out that python is introducing {} for both dict() and set() :o

Comment: @gsk: A list with two elements `[1, 2]`; a list with one element: `[1]`; a list without elements `[]`.  Seems pretty explicit to me.  I know the same example would look different for sets in Python 3 – this is about the only design decision for 3.x I don't like.

Comment: @gsk and I think twice when list() is called without parameters. [] is more explicit to me, and kind of is by definition... since that is the definition.

Comment: Ok Ok :D don't gang up on me. I too once preferred [] to list(), but since then my tastes have changed. If I had only commented several months ago, I might've fallen into friendlier company. [] it is

Answer (score 5):

The two are completely equivalent, except that it is possible to redefine the identifier `list` to refer to a different object. Accordingly, it is safer to use `[]` unless you want to be able to redefine `list` to be a new type.

Technically, using `[]` will be very slightly faster, because it avoids name lookup. This is unlikely to be significant in any case, unless the programme is allocating lists constantly and furiously.

As Sven notes, `list` has other uses, but of course the question does not ask about those.

Comment: These two are not completely equivalent. There are cases they work differently.

Comment: @Scott: Excluding the case where `list` has been reassigned (which this answer addresses), they're equivalent in all meaningful ways by the language spec. There might be differences in how much preallocation of the underlying `list` each one does, and the precise time each takes to execute, but they don't *work* differently in any meaningful way.