# Difference between [] and list doesn't run the program

Tags: python, list, range

In the listRange part if I use `[(range(1, num +1)]`, instead of `list(range(1, num+1))`, The program doesn't work why ?

```
num = int(input("Please choose a number to divide: "))

listRange = list(range(1,num+1))

divisorList = []

for number in listRange:
    if num % number == 0:
        divisorList.append(number)

print(divisorList)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the interactive mode, and try e.g. `[range(1, 5)]`? What do you get? How does it differ from `list(range(1, 5))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mylist = list() vs mylist = \[\] in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780357/mylist-list-vs-mylist-in-python)

Comment: ^See duplicate answer - "The list() built-in is useful to convert some other iterable to a list"

Comment: I got unsupported operand type if I use [range (1, num + 1)], but I get the desired solution if I use range(1, num + 1) or list(range(1, num +1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, `range()` returns a range object.

With list(...) you're converting the range object (which is an iterable) to a list.
With [] you're wrapping the range object in a list, w/o iterating the content.

```
print([(range(1))]) # [range(0, 1)]
print(list(range(1))) # [0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much...I just joined today and you guys replied within a minute...this is so cool.

Answer (score 0):

as an additional option you can 'unpack' the range object with the asterisk/star(some call it "splat") operator

```
[*range(7)]
Out[213]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```