# removing duplicates of a list of sets

Tags: python, list, duplicates, set, unique

I have a list of sets :

```
L = [set([1, 4]), set([1, 4]), set([1, 2]), set([1, 2]), set([2, 4]), set([2, 4]), set([5, 6]), set([5, 6]), set([3, 6]), set([3, 6]), set([3, 5]), set([3, 5])]
```

(actually in my case a conversion of a list of reciprocal tuples)

and I want to remove duplicates to get :

```
L = [set([1, 4]), set([1, 2]), set([2, 4]), set([5, 6]), set([3, 6]), set([3, 5])]
```

But if I try :

```
>>> list(set(L))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Or

```
>>> list(np.unique(L))
TypeError: cannot compare sets using cmp()
```

How do I get a list of sets with distinct sets?

Comment: One way could be to convert the list of `set` to `list` of `list` and then remove the duplicates and then converting the `list` elements back to `set`.

Comment: @ZdaR I'm going to say this in bold: **Your hint is wrong.** Following the part of your instructions which say "*convert the list of `set` to `list` of `list` and then remove the dupicates*", we get that `list(map(list, [{3, 11}, {11, 3}]))` outputs `[[3, 11], [11, 3]]`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The best way is to convert your sets to `frozenset`s (which are hashable) and then use `set` to get only the unique sets, like this

```
>>> list(set(frozenset(item) for item in L))
[frozenset({2, 4}),
 frozenset({3, 6}),
 frozenset({1, 2}),
 frozenset({5, 6}),
 frozenset({1, 4}),
 frozenset({3, 5})]
```

If you want them as sets, then you can convert them back to `set`s like this

```
>>> [set(item) for item in set(frozenset(item) for item in L)]
[{2, 4}, {3, 6}, {1, 2}, {5, 6}, {1, 4}, {3, 5}]
```

---

If you want the order also to be maintained, while removing the duplicates, then you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), like this

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> [set(i) for i in OrderedDict.fromkeys(frozenset(item) for item in L)]
[{1, 4}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {5, 6}, {3, 6}, {3, 5}]
```

Comment: @PM2Ring It exists in 2.7 so that statement is not strictly true.

Comment: @DanD: Oops! I originally just looked at the [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), where it says "New in version 3.1". But I just now checked in the Python 2 docs & it says "New in version 2.7."; I should've checked there to see if it had been back-ported. Sorry about that. I'll remove my comment(s).

Answer (score 4):

An alternative using a loop:

```
result = list()
for item in L:
    if item not in result:
        result.append(item)
```

Comment: It is better to use `[]` than `list()` to create a list

Comment: Why is that Bhargav Rao?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: it's because `[]` is literal syntax (allowing the empty list to be instantiated at compile time) whereas `list()` is a function call (the function name must be looked up at run time and then called to return the empty list). The latter is slightly more expensive.

Comment: My preference for `list()` is merely aesthetic. Up until today I didn't even know it was slightly more expensive. If that's the only issue, I don't think it's that big of a deal.

Comment: I could not find verifiable info, but it looks like operator overload to me; in that case, [] will call list() in the background... for most cases, the difference, if any, will be in the nanosecond scale! :)

Comment: Other thing is you can shadow the list. So its better to prefer literals

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I investigated a little and [they behave differently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736693/creating-a-list-in-python-something-sneaky-going-on), but it's an insignificant difference, as you say.

Comment: @thefourtheye I think that's a bit of a stretch, unless I'm missing something. You'd have to make the mistake of assigning to `list` instead of assigning `list()` to something.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative

```
yourNewSet = map(set,list(set(map(tuple,yourSet))))
```

Comment: **This answer is wrong**. Two equal sets can be mapped to two different tuples. I have seen this happen. For example: `ss = [{3, 11}, {11, 3}]; list(map(tuple, ss))` outputs `[(3, 11), (11, 3)]`

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative.

```
import itertools
list_sets = [set(['a', 'e', 'f']), set(['c', 'b', 'f']), set(['a', 'e', 'f']), set(['a', 'd']), set(['a', 'e', 'f'])]

lists = [list(s) for s in list_sets] # convert a list of sets to a list of lists
lists.sort()
lists_remove_duplicates = [lists for lists,_ in itertools.groupby(lists)]
print(lists_remove_duplicates)

# output
[['a', 'd'], ['a', 'e', 'f'], ['c', 'b', 'f']]
```