# Python type() function returns a callable

Tags: python, types, module, callable

`type(object)` returns type of an object.

```
>>> type(__builtins__)
<type 'module'>
>>> name = type(__builtins__)
>>> type(name)
<type 'type'>
>>> name
<type 'module'>

>>> name('my_module')
<module 'my_module' (built-in)>
>>> name('xyz')
<module 'xyz' (built-in)>
>>>
```

In this syntax,

```
my_module = type(__builtins__)('my_module')
```

`type(__builtins__)` should return callable object that takes `('my_module')` as argument. `type(object)` returns callable object?

How to understand what this is doing?

Comment: Yes, `type` returns a type object. Type objects are callable.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @vaultah Do you mean, `type(__builtins__)`  displays `<type 'module'>` on stdout and returns callable object?

Comment: `<type 'module'>` is the `repr` of the `module` type object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  I can apply `('my_module')` to an object, if it is of type `function`. Is `type(__builtins__)` returning some function?

Comment: It's returning a type, i.e. a class. Calling a class returns an instance of said class.

Comment: What? You can't apply (?) 'my_module' to *any* function, only ones which accepts a single positional parameter. But `type(__builtins__)` is returning a type object, which is callable like a function.

Comment: Maybe if you explain what you are trying to accomplish with `my_module = type(__builtins__)('my_module')`. The object `my_module` which you are creating this way isn't going to be very useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's run through some examples:

---

```
>>> type(int)
<class 'type'>
```

So, since `type(int)` returns a `type`, it makes sense that

```
>>> type(int)(12)
<class 'int'>
```

since

```
>>> type(12)
<class 'int'>
```

**More importantly:**

```
>>> (type(int)(12) == type(12)) and (type(int)(12) is type(12))
True
```

---

Now, if you instead do:

```
>>> type(int())
<class 'int'>
```

which is also expected since

```
>>> (int() == 0) and (int() is 0)
True
```

and

```
>>> (type(int()) = type(0)) and (type(int()) is type(0))
True
```

---

So, putting things together:

- `int` is an object of type `type`
- `int()` is an (integer) object of type `int`

---

Another example:

```
>>> type(str())
<class 'str'>
```

which means that

```
>>> (type(str())() == '') and (type(str())() is '')
True
```

therefore, it behaves just like a string object:

```
>>> type(str())().join(['Hello', ', World!'])
'Hello, World!'
```

---

I have the feeling that I might have made this seem much more complicated than it actually is... it isn't!

---

`type()` returns the class of an object. So:

- `type(12)` is just an ugly way of writing `int`
- `type(12)(12)` is just an ugly way of writing `int(12)`

So, "Yes!", `type()` returns a callable. But it's much better to think about it as (from [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) )

> *class **type**(object)*
>
> With one argument, return the type of an object. The return value is a type object and generally the same object as returned by object.__class__.

Comment: Can I say, `x = 1` is nothing but `x = int(1)` internally? Only difference is, `x=int(1)` is more OOP way of writing python code. Guido provided syntactic sugar `x=1` from math sense.

Comment: am still not clear,If x=myClass() is not confusing  then how y=int() is confusing. If my team decides for writing oop style python code, then x=1 looks like math equation despite int(1) gets executed internally.

Comment: Python does not call `int()` when you run `x=1`. `x=1` is faster to type, is faster to run, as is the most pythonic way of writing code. See: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736693/creating-a-list-in-python-something-sneaky-going-on) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790860/and-vs-list-and-dict-which-is-better)

Answer (score 3):

The *type()* function returns the class of an object.  In the case of `type(__builtins__)` it returns a *Module* type.   The semantics of module are detailed at:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#modules

The source code for CPython has this in Objects/moduleobject.c::*module_init()*:

```
static char *kwlist[] = {"name", "doc", NULL};
PyObject *dict, *name = Py_None, *doc = Py_None;
if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "U|O:module.__init__",
                                 kwlist, &name, &doc))
```

That means you can call (instantiate) module objects with the *name* of the module as a required argument and the docstring as an optional argument.